# How to have the same coordinates for an object in Edit and Object Mode?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I created an animated torus and afterwards I wanted to rotate it (and the animation) around the Z-axis of the world, so I used an *Empty* object , I made it parent of the torus and I rotated the empty.

I would like to have the new values of the keyframes after transformations and , it the same, the new values of coordinates of the tore's center in *Object Mode* like in *Edit Mode*.

In *Object Mode* it shows the old values!

I would also like to know:

- Is it possible , after the transformation , to keep the new position (and animation) of the tore AND to delete Empty object?
- Is it possible to do all this without to use Empty object? (easier of course!)

Thanks !

--the animation is a translation with many pauses, torus goes from (x,y,0) to (0,0,0) .

This is the torus before the rotation ( the coordinates are the same in Object Mode and Edit Mode )

[image]

After the rotation of the Empty object the coordinates are different between Object and Edit Mode

[image]

Comment: The animation is only a  translation ( with many pauses) to the origin of the World

Comment: Looks like you animated your torus in *Edit Mode* instead of *Object Mode*, you don't need empties for simple animations

Comment: But when I rotate the tore in Edit Mode then the tore don't go to the center of the world!

Comment: Sorry @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I didn't understand your reponse !!!    Are there other solutions than to remake my animation in _Edit Mode_ ?

Comment: No, **don't** make it in edit mode, animate it in **Object Mode** only, unless your are trying to make shape changes

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos,  I'm very very sorry for my bad English  ,   the tore went from (x1,y1,0) to (0,0,0)  , after rotation it goes from (x2,y2,0) to (0,0,0) . I made this animation in _Object Mode_ .

Comment: You have a different number of verts selected in these screen shots. What you have selected determines where the average center is. That's why you are seeing different numbers.

Comment: @Mentalist, no,  the number of verts selected is the same for these two screen shots. How do you see the number of verts **selected** in these screen shots?

Comment: My mistake. Sorry for the confusion. I was looking at the wrong part of the screen shots. Could you post the .blend using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: I re-read your question and I think I understand your problem now. I just posted an answer. Please give it a try and accept the answer if it solves your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, You can Apply Transformations, the object will stay in the same place but the origin will became the Center and location will be the (0,0,0).

Comment: No , for example in the frame 532, before rotation,  the coordinates of torus are (1.62,4.97,0) , after rotation 18° around the Z-axe of the world , the new coordinates are (0,5.23,0) in _Edit Mode_ but in _Object Mode_ there are always the old coordinates. Is it possible to have the new coordinates in _Object Mode_ for all frames?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your issue, you created an animation but then had to reposition the whole animation, and the way you did that was by parenting it to an Empty and rotating the Empty -  but now it's inconvenient/confusing when editing because the coordinates you see in Edit Mode and Object Mode don't match (even when the Median Point of the selection is the same as that of the Object Origin).

### Why this happens

This is a result of the coordinates now being dependent on the Empty. And while we can view the coordinates of the median relative to the World (Global) or relative to the Object container (Local), there is no option to view the coordinates relative to the Parent.

### A possible solution

(Save your file before proceeding)

With only your torus Object selected:

**Object > Animation > Bake Action...**

[image: Baking the action of the selected Object]

You have some options to choose from:

[image: Bake Action - options]

Here's a summary of what the options mean:

- Only Selected [only do it for the object(s) you have selected]
- Visual Keying [re-keyframe it just the way it looks]
- Clear Constraints [removes constraints once finished]
- Clear Parents [removes parenting once finished]
- Overwrite Current Action [change *this* keyframing, don't make a separate action]

This will recalculate the keyframes based on the object's visual position (meaning the data will reflect the way it looks, taking into account the effects of Parents, Constraints, etc).

After baking, you may end up with more keyframes than you need. You can use your previously saved file as a reference of which keyframes were your originals and delete any you decide you don't need.

In any case, after doing this you will no longer need your Empty, and your coordinates will appear as you'd normally expect them to in Edit Mode. As you can imagine, this can be a fix for many similar situations, not just your specific case.

### Example files

Recreation of your .blend here: 
[image]

The result after baking the animation: [image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Mentalist for your help , your idea is an issue but in my case I 'm not sure that it is faster than to use _Clear and keep transformation_  for each keyframe. Maybe , is it possible to transform this simple animation into a path and then rotate the path as I want ? Thanks again !

Comment: Well go ahead and try both. Do some tests. See what works for you. I know of no way to Clear and Keep Transformation *for each keyframe*. As for transforming the animation into a path, you might want to check out the [Motion Trail add-on](https://vimeo.com/20659756), as it seems to be close to what you're describing.

Answer (score -2):

One idea is to use *Clear Parent*  (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and choose *Clear and keep transformation* but it is only for one keyframe , we must repeat this operation for all keyframes.

Are there other solutions?
Thanks!